# Model becomes NULL when Date property is invalid on an ASP.NET Core API action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2

On an Asp.Net Core 2.2 I have the following **API** controller Action:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([FromBody]BookModel model) {
}
```

Where `BookModel` is the following:

```
public class BookModel { 
  public Int32? CategoryId { get; set; }
  public String Title { get; set; }
  public DateTime? PublishedAt { get; set; }       
}
```

**Question 1**

Both `CategoryId` and `PublishedAt` are required ...

I made both optional so that it passes the ModelBinder even if value are invalid.

Then, in the action, I validate the model and return a lista of errors.

Does this make sense?

**Question 2**

When I submit and invalid date (Example: 20190228. Valid would be 2019-02-28) the model in the controller becomes null.

Any idea why? This seems very strange.

Comment: If the date is nullable `DateTime?` it sounds confusing to me that it is `Required`. It it's really required - why not just make it `DateTime`?

Comment: I updated my question. In fact the error is due to missing the "dashes".

Comment: May I ask why you are using the `FromBody` attribute in your controller Action, is this an API or a web application, if the latter why are you not just posting the data as a form with Model binding?

Comment: @DmitryPavlov If you put, for example, the date DateTime to nullable and if the date is invalid you will get the default system date, e.g. 01/01/0001 00:00:00. Wouldn't be better to get null and validate it against null?

Comment: @RyanWilson This is an API. I am posting using Angular 7 HTTP Client

Comment: @MiguelMoura You may want to modify your post to say that this is an API project.

Comment: @RyanWilson Just did ...

Comment: @MiguelMoura IMO there is nothing wrong with having extra validation on your API controller, but I would think you would want to validate the values client side as well to try and prevent passing invalid data to the API controller, and I agree with Dmitry about making the values nullable when they are required seems like a bad approach.

Comment: @DmitryPavlov If you want to see client side validation message for required attribute of none-nullable types like int, DateTime and decimal they must be marked as nullable ?. Otherwise they will get a default value of 0 by default and the required message will not be triggered on client side.

Comment: You should share your controller action, maybe you are not returning the model to the view.